# iOS Extension Logs Not Appearing In Xcode Console

Tags: xcode, logging, ios-extensions

Main app logs are appearing in the extension logs but as soon as I attach the extension, the Xcode console goes blank and stops outputting anything. It can appear in the mac console app, but I need it to appear in Xcode console.

I ran the main app and the main app in the target. Whilst running, I attached the extension and triggered it by sharing to the app.

I checked the Info.plist file and could not find anything.
I added OS_ACTIVITY_MODE to default in the scheme settings for the extension and that did not work either.